# Matching characters after a certain word and stop matching before this same word

Tags: python, regex

I would like a regex to match all characters after a certain word appear, and stop matching after if this same word appears (or if the expression ends). For example if I want to match every character after "by" or "per" and stop when "by" or "per" appears again:

- Order my clothes by color and by size => ['color and', 'size']
- You much do you spend per week and per category? => ['week and', 'category?']

So far, I have done the following:

```
(by|per)\s(\w+)
```

But only gives me one word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(by|per)\s+(.*?)(?=\s*(?:\b(?:by|per)\b|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIF5X1/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(by|per)` - Group 1: `by` or `per` words
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible up to the first occurrence of...
- `(?=\s*(?:\b(?:by|per)\b|$))` - a sequence of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:\b(?:by|per)\b|$)` - either of

    - `\b(?:by|per)\b` - `by` or `per` whole words
    - `|` - or
    - `$` - end of string.